# PhoneGap: diagnostic plugin is not working in iphone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to use diagnostic plugin in my ios app built by phonegap Build. 
It's working fine for android but it's not working in ios.

It is not showing any error in remote debug (console).

I am using following two files to build this app:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Using PhoneGap Audio Media</title>
     <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

    <script src='cordova.js'></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeviceReady() {

    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabledSetting(function(enabled){
            if(enabled)
            {
                alert("Location Setting is enabled");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Location Setting is disabled");
            }
        }, function(error){
            alert("The following error occurred: "+error);
        });
                }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>

</head>

<body>
 Checking...
</body>
</html>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.location" version="1.0.0"    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>Location Tester</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>

<gap:platform name="ios" />
<gap:platform name="android" />
<gap:platform name="winphone" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

 <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-flashlight" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" source="npm" />

<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
 <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />

 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />

 <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="false" />

 <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />

 <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
 </widget>
```

The plugin I am trying to use in this app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic

I am not getting any error. I reasearched alot about this issue but no vain.
I'll really appreciate any response.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that the exact config.xml you are using? Because I don't see any reference to `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` in it. Hence is the plugin actually being installed in the project?

I'd expect to see `<gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22" />` if you're using the [legacy branch](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/tree/api-22).

Or `<gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api" />` if you're using the master branch to build against Android API 23 with [Cordova 6.0.0 on Phonegap Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/09/phonegap_6_now_on_build/):

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0" />
```

Other than that, you usage of the JS API in index.html looks correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It really helped me and saved my time. 
I'll also help people like you by using my knowledge. May God Bless you